# simulate status using adb & telnet

Tags: android, adb

I am trying to understand how to simulate statuses (battery, sensors, etc) using adb and telnet. I am using emulator.

On doing:

adb shell battery  
there is no change in simulator status

But on doing:

adb shell dumpsys battery set level 5
I can see change in value.

I therefore would like to ask:

1. Is there any reason why "adb shell battery " does not work with emulator?
2. setting value with dumpsys does works, although it is documneted that dumpsys is used for dumping status (and there is no documentation for other usages). and the questions, is whether we can use dumpsys to set other statuses, such as sensors ? if yes - how we can find out how to set other values ?
3. What is ther purpose of telnet to the device ? Seems that some attributes can be set using telnet and some using the adb utility. Why are these 2 utilities required and not only one ?

Comment: ad 1) read documentation about `adb shell` command ad 2) `adb shell dumpsys -l`